# field image didn't appears in my view

Tags: drupal, e-commerce

I am using Drupal commerce, I have been wanting to create views for recently added products, actually that works (pretty easy) but when I want to add the field image, images didn't appear. I will try to illustrate my steps: 
1) create new view, show: content; of: product display; sorted by: newest first. 
2) add relationship (content: referenced products) then I required it.
what I did wrong!
thanks for any answer.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your View settings? Also of the Product Image field settings?

Comment: @ScottAnderson i afraid i m not used to use this forum , i tried to add images but i couldn't :p

Comment: Did you add the image field from the referenced products (i.e the image field, using the relationship like "(Referenced Product) Image") in your view ? If you already add the image field, make sure you choose "Use relationship : Referenced product" in the image field settings, otherwise Views will keep looking for this field on the product display, not on the product itself.

Comment: Glad to help ! I post my previous comment as answer, could you accept it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add the image field from the referenced product (i.e the image field, using the relationship like "(Referenced Product) Image") in your view. In Drupal Commerce, image fields on products are usually product field and not product display field as they might change across products variations.

If you already add the image field, make sure you choose "Use relationship : Referenced product" in the image field settings, otherwise Views will keep looking for this field on the product display, not on the product itself.